# Checkbox on change event is not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, safari, onchange

Thanks in advance for the help on this. I have a special requirement on my page where I needed a checkbox to "act" like a radio button, so only one can be checked at a time. To achieve that I used this snippet below"

```
<script>
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $('input:checked').not($(this)).closest('.w-checkbox').click();
});
</script>
```

It works perfectly on Chrome. However, it doesn't work on Safari and allows more than one checkbox to be clicked. I was wondering if anyone had ideas on how to solve this because I have tried many alternatives and unfortunately need to have the checkbox

Comment: Thanks for the tips but I'm still having the issue in Safari...

going to have to keep researching this.

Really appreciate it though

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to uncheck a checkbox is by changing the `checked` property.

```js
$('input:checkbox.w-checkbox').change(function() {
  $('input:checkbox.w-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="w-checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="w-checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="w-checkbox" />
```

Comment: Slight optimisation: You can just use `.not(this)` to avoid the need to create another jQuery object.